# Restrict creation of duplicate contacts for an Account

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement that for an account there should be unique email id for every related contact. But in my code it is not working as per the requirement, it is checking all the contacts irrespective of Account. But I need to check only Account related contacts email id's.Here is my code please help me where I am doing wrong

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert,before update)
 {

  set<ID> accId = new set<ID>();
   list<string> ContactEmails=new list<string>();
    for(Contact conVar:trigger.new)
    {
        ContactEmails.add(conVar.email);
        accId.add(conVar.AccountId);
    }

    system.debug('ContactEmails ************' +ContactEmails);

    list<Contact> listOfDuplicateContacts=[select id,email,Account.ID from Contact where email in :ContactEmails AND AccountID IN : accId];
      system.debug('listOfDuplicateContacts ************' +listOfDuplicateContacts);

    for(Contact con:trigger.new)
    {
        if(trigger.isInsert){
        if(listOfDuplicateContacts.size()!=0)
        {
            con.addError('Contact email already exists with this name');
        }
        }
        if(trigger.isUpdate)
        {
           for(Contact oldContact :trigger.old)
           {
               if(con.Email!=oldContact.Email && listOfDuplicateContacts.size()!=0)
               {
                   con.addError('Contact email already exists with this name');
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need code for this requirement.

Comment: Hi Adrian Larson, can explain me how can I achieve it without coding. I also tried Duplicate rules but it is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a trigger for this requirement, you can achieve this with a simple `workflow` and `field update`.

So here are the steps you need to follow for this

- Create a text field on `Contact` i.e. for example : `Account Contact Key` and mark it as unique case sensitive.
- Create a workflow on `Contact` object and add a `field update` on it to populate the above mentioned field with `AccountId + '-' + Email` (You can replace any field with Email on which you want to identify the duplicates)

Now whenever a record is created with the same `Email` as the other `Contact` under that same `Account`, Salesforce would throw you an exception as you have marked that field as `unique case sensitive`.

**Note :** Using this above approach would need you to invoke the workflow one time so as to populate the above mentioned field for the already existing records.

If you still want to go with the trigger approach, then you will have to change your code to check the records Account wise instead of checking against all the records.

So your simplified trigger code should look like

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert,before update){
    set<ID> accId = new set<ID>();
    list<string> ContactEmails=new list<string>();
    for(Contact conVar:trigger.new){
        ContactEmails.add(conVar.email);
        accId.add(conVar.AccountId);
    }

    system.debug('ContactEmails ************' +ContactEmails);
    Map<Id,Integer> mapAccounts = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT  AccountId, count(Id) ContactCount FROM Contact where email in :ContactEmails AND AccountID IN : accId GROUP BY AccountId]){
        mapAccounts.put(Id.valueOf(ar.get('AccountId')), Integer.valueOf(ar.get('ContactCount')));
    }

    system.debug('listOfDuplicateContacts ************' +listOfDuplicateContacts);

    for(Contact con:trigger.new) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            if(mapAccounts.containsKey(con.AccountId)) {
                con.addError('Contact email already exists with this name');
            }
        } else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
            if(con.Email!=Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).Email && mapAccounts.containsKey(con.AccountId)){
                con.addError('Contact email already exists with this name');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @siri if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.